# How we can load a class from different location?

Tags: java, classloader

I've written a program in directory

```
C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.6\bin\
```

and I want to load a class from different location i.e.

```
D:\\MyProgs\
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set Path (environment variable) of `C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.6\bin`. If you have `Win` OS then open System Properties (Control Panel) + Advanced + Environment Variables) to set or create new `Path` variable.

If you want to run a class which is located at another folder then you have to use -classpath switch. In fact both, java compiler (javac.exe) and java launcher (java.exe) require the location of classes and you may specify using `-classpath` or `-cp` switch.

For instance:

```
D:\MyProgs\>java -cp .;"C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.6\bin" NameOfClass
```

Comment: Thank you sir,

But the exact problem with my program is ,I'm developing a project for "Java IDE".

I can write a program and can execute the same program efficiently through my "Java IDE". But I'm unable to execute a program which is typed and compiled in my "Java IDE".

Hence, please tell me the precise solution to run java program through my "Java IDE".

Thank you Sir!!!

Comment: @user1092076 - Which IDE do you have?

Answer (score 0):

If classes in your "D:\MyProgs\" then you can add that directory to CLASSPATH and that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your IDE, you can add external libraries to the project or modify the classpath; then, `import` the class where you need it.

You can then load the class with `Class.forName()`. or simply instantiate it.